# SQL query to retrieve SUM in various DATE ranges based on timestamp with timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I have the same question as this - [SQL query to retrieve SUM in various DATE ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568353/sql-query-to-retrieve-sum-in-various-date-ranges) - except that instead of having dates, I have timestamps, and when I try to do `year(created)` (created is a timestamp), I get an error:

> function year(timestamp with time zone) does not exist

In sum, I'm trying to get the same output as the request in the link I pasted above (a list of sums by month), but the year and month functions don't seem to work on a timestamp with timezone.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
 SELECT SUM(totalprice), date_part('year', your_time_stamp_column),
 date_part('month', your_time_stamp_column) 

from sales
group by date_part('year', your_time_stamp_column), 
date_part('month', your_time_stamp_column)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html